# Why does HttpRequest not work on Windows but works on Mac?

Tags: c#, .net-core, httprequest

My partner who uses a Mac can run the program without any problem but when I try to run it it gives

> WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

I've tried to copy the request URL (after the string is built) and the browser gives me the expected answer.

The code is this:

```
double SearchLatitude = 41.480687;
double SearchLongitude = -8.527346;
double Radius = 10; // km  
int maxResults = 5;
string bingMapsKey = "MyKey";
string requestUrl = string.Format("http://spatial.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/data/c2ae584bbccc4916a0acf75d1e6947b4/NavteqEU/NavteqPOIs" +
            "?spatialFilter=nearby({0},{1},{2})&$filter=EntityTypeID Eq 5400&$top={3}&key={4}", SearchLatitude, SearchLongitude, Radius, maxResults,bingMapsKey);

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Could this be a Windows problem?

Comment: If that is your real bingMapsKey then you shouldn't have posted it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman no, it is not

Comment: @HenkHolterman it's modified, but i can change it to not look real

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to check is the regional settings (1.2 vs 1,2).

And always best to use

```
//string requestUrl = string.Format("http://spatial.virtualearth.net/REST/...", ...);
  string requestUrl = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "http://spatial.virtualearth.net/REST/...", ...);
```

Comment: Thank you! But can you explain me the diference between each approach?

Comment: Well, look at the exact URL produced initially on the Mac and the Windws PCs. They would have been different. Only one can be right.